# Scope_Identity() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**What is the equal code in EntityFramework to this sql code?**

```
select Scope_Identity()
```

I want to get the id of the last record that i have inserted to database in EF.

Comment: You can't directly invoke that SQL function. However, if you define your table's column to be based on an `INT IDENTITY` field, EF should automatically update your entity object with the new value after the data has been inserted into SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ensure that your key property is mapped with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity` ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130703042422/http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/) you can find some more about this setting). This should be used as default when generating the model from MS SQL database where the key column is defined with `IDENTITY`. After that it is enough to call `SaveChanges` on the context and [the key property will be automatically filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework/5212787#5212787) for you.