# Get Auto Identity Key after Insert via EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

Is there a straight forward way of retrieving a DB auto generated primary key when adding a record via Entity Framework 4.1?

For example:

```
dbcontext.Entity_Tables.Add(new Entity_Table { item1 = val1, item2 = val2 });
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
newPK = ???;
```

The SQL equivalent would be:

```
newPK = executeOnDB("INSERT INTO Entity_Table (item1, item2) VALUES (val1, val2);SELECT @@Indentity";);
```

BTW I'm using MySQL but the SQL would be the same as on MSSQL

Comment: I just want to point out that `SELECT @@Identity` is NOT a good way to get the last inserted id. You should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Thanks Icarus. I never realized that. Guess I should update some of my older apps too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-retrieve-Id-of-inserted-entity-using-Entity-framework

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I believe EF should update your entity object with the identity:

```
var entity = new Entity_Table { item1 = val1, item2 = val2 };
dbcontext.Entity_Tables.Add(entity);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
int newPK = entity.ID;
```

Comment: I just confirmed that's exactly what it does. Many thanks ob!

Comment: When I insert, there is an InsertBefore trigger on the table which adds its own properties, and so, even if save changes is executing, that insert is replaced by the insert before, and so, the ID returned for me is 0, and the actual value of ID is something else. In that case how do i get the value?

Comment: How to get Auto Identity Key before Insert via EF?

Comment: Guess this is before save changes then how to refetch only ID
 int newPK = entity.ID;