# Using a new datacontext from WebAPI doesn't find newly added data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So I have this method in a WebAPI controller.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Model model)
{
   using(var dc = new DataContext())
   {
      dc.MyData.Add(model);
      dc.SaveChanges();
   }   
   //logic that requires the data to be saved first
   using(var dc = new DataContext())
   {
      dc.MyData.Find(model.ID); //this returns null, even tho in the DB I see my model get added to MyData
   }
}
```

The first `using` statement saves to the database, however the second `using` statement can't find the newly added data. In or normal MVC controller the second using statement works as expected.

Is there a reason the second `using` statement can't find the `MyData` record from WebAPI?

Comment: take a look what is inside your model.ID property. May be there is a 0 value. Is data stored in database?

Comment: Is Model.ID an Auto Identity key? If so, Model.ID should be populated when you save ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435462/get-auto-identity-key-after-insert-via-ef)), but if not then we might need to know more about your data model.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is generated behind the scenes for Entity Framework. Probably the ID  you are using has 0, because you got It from the parameter.´

If the Add method succed, this statement above should return the last item inserted, that's what you want:

```
using(var dc = new DataContext())
{
  var myModel = dc.MyData.Last();
}
```