# Return last insert id with LINQ to EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So I've seen this...

[Get Auto Identity Key after Insert via EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435462/get-auto-identity-key-after-insert-via-ef)

Seems like a lot to go through and I notice `DbContext.SaveChanges()` returns `int`.

So what I want to know is, can't we just do something like this:

```
public string username { get; protected set; }
public string password { get; protected set; }

public int RegisterUser()
{
    DbContext.users u = new DbContext.users();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        u.username = username;
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        u.password = password;
    }

    DbContext.users.Add(u);
    return DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Its not clear by the intellisense what the int value is that SaveChanges returns, so I'm just trying to figure out, is this a 0/1 value for "yes it worked" or "no it broke" or is this the id value of the new record?

Comment: The integer return value is: >The number of objects in an Added, Modified, or Deleted state when SaveChanges was called.

Comment: After you call `SaveChanges()`, your `u` object will have the updated Id property.  The return value from `SaveChanges()` is the number of objects written to the database.

Answer (score 2):

after calling `db.SaveChanges` when inserting an item with an Identity Key, that object's ID will be set.

I.E. after you call `db.SaveChanges`, u.ID will be set

Answer (score 1):

To get the ID (auto generated) you could check the user object.

```
u.ID //assuming it exists.
```

the int returned by `SaveChanges()` is the number of objects written to the underlying database.