# How do I get the next auto increment value for a SQL table and use it?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have linked a basic database containing 2 tables, Login and Customer:

- `Login` contains (`CustomerID`, `loginID`, `password`)
- `Customer` contains (`CustomerID`, `name`, `last`, `dob`)

`CustomerID` is primary key in both fields, and is the auto-increment value in the Login table.

When I want to register a new user, I want to FIRST populate Login table (which has `CustomerID` as an auto-increment value)

How do I get the next auto-increment value from `Login` so I could use it when populating the `Customer` table?

I am using SQL Server 12.

Comment: I had trouble understanding your table schema. Can you please make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the autoincrement-generated id value from newly created `Login` records so you can use them in the other tables?

Comment: What are you using to access the tables and database? Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Stored Procedure to handle this logic, then you can do this in one transaction by getting the `Scope_Identity` value from the newly inserted record, and then using this value to insert into the next table.

`Scope_Identity` is definitely the way to go here, and you will get the latest ID within the scope of your call to the SP.

If this is a two step process via Entity Framework, then take a look at [How can I retrieve Id of inserted entity using Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(MAX(CustomerID),0)+1 from Customer
```

Comment: can you please show me the whole statement? is that an sql statement?

Comment: @kayze Yes, this is a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'Login_Table'
```

Seek the value of **Auto_increment** or other details

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Guid` in your C# code and set that as the CustomerID, (`Guid custID = new Guid();`).
`Guid`s are the type `uniqueidentifier` in SQL Server.

Are you using Entity Framework? It's a great way to access a SQL database from a .NET application.

Comment: sorry i cant use guid the database structure is using autoincrement for login table, i cant modify that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql queries:

let your inertIntoLoginTable function return an integer which is the [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)
 or [@@Identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

If you are using an ORM like Entity Framework, the id will be set to the object after insertion in the database:

`Login.loginID` will be the last id inserted after you call `dbContext.SaveChanges();`