# How do I update WPF context on local network

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4

I have issue with WPF on network, I published the application on IIS and install it over the network, let us say we have 2 computer (server and client), the server computer to create new item and the client to shows the items as list.

What I want to ask about is it should when the server add new item in the same time he/her push the save button it should appear in the other computer on the network (client computer)

But it doesn't ! When I check I found the server updated his context but the client still have the old context.

I don't know how can I update the context in client server knowing that the client computer just for show (TV screen connected with computer)

I hope this clear, and I hope I find answers for my issue.

Comment: how you would update the server and client?

Comment: @DhavalPatel If I add new item and use context.SaveChanges(); on the client, how can I invoke the client for this change

Comment: both server and client use same db then you don't need to anything it will automatically update are you using a diff db?

Comment: I think the mentioned link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270599/entity-framework-refresh-context

Comment: The Database update but the entity doesn't, and how can I access for client context from server ?

Comment: it's not possible in your case if you want then you can use duplex WCF service.

Comment: @DhavalPatel, Thanks for your time, Is there any good guide about how to use duplex WCF service.

Comment: use the mentioned link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF