# Entity Framework - Identity Key cannot be sent to controller to Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am successfully saving a entity to my database and getting back the PK ID that the Database has generated.

```
repository.InsertOrUpdate(viewModel.Entity);

repository.Save();

viewModel.Entity.ID  // This property will now have the ID  that the database has generated.
```

So all well and good.

However, when I send the Veiwmodel back to the view from the controller

```
return View(viewModel);
```

and using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Entity.Id)
```

The ID appears as 0. So therefore when I try to post an update, EF thinks its a new record, using this syntax

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Entity entity)
{
        if (entity.Id == default(int))
        {
            entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
            entity.LastEdit = DateTime.Now;

            Context.T.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entity.LastEdit = DateTime.Now;
            Context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
  }
```

Anything obvious I am doing wrong in which I can't get the created ID to the view?

******** Edit *********

Strangely, using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Entity.Id)
```

will show 0 as above. However, if I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Entity.Id)
```

It will show the correct ID value.. (Why?)

But when I press send the ActionResult post still returns 0...

Thanks

Comment: You still can send the entity via viewData or TempData

Comment: Sending the entity information via a viewmodel works as all of the other properties in the entity are rendered correctly on the view, its just the ID never is..

Comment: Are you sure you get the id after insertion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework

Comment: Positive, I used a breakpoint on the return View(viewModel) and the ID does have the correct ID. Will check the link, thanks

Comment: Oh wait i justn oticed you are calling `m.Entity.ID` I think it's `m.ID`

Comment: I can see why you have said that but I put entity as I have another entity inside the viewmodel, entityA and entityB, hence why its the entity class then the .id, cheers though!

Comment: I guess in your view you have `@model myapp.Models.Entity` at the begining ?  so you can call it like `@Model.ID` normally

Comment: I have @model myapp.domain.ViewModel (so basically the two entities wrapped)