# access object properties after it was added to db

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a create method where I add a new Employee Object to the database, after the employee is added I want to go into the edit page to be able to enter more details about the employee if I wish.

The Edit action method takes 1 parameter, the EmployeeID, however this EmployeeID is dynamically assigned by the database once an object is added to the Employee Table. How do I access the ID of the newly added employee after _db.SaveChanges() within the same action method?

here is what part of my method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Employee Employee) {
 _db.Employees.Add(Employee);
 _db.SaveChanges();
 //access the employee and gets its id???
 //var id = id???
 return RedirectToAction("EditEmployeeViewModel", new { id = id});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use this:

```
Employee.Id
```

The `Employee` object is synchronized with the changes you make to the `db`. Hence, when you add this objects to the `Employees` and call the `SaveChanges`, this objects will be saved to the `db` and it's state will be updated, having the `Id` of the `Employee`.

Specifically, as it stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework):

> Entity framework by default follows each INSERT with SELECT
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY() when autogenerated Ids are used.

Answer (score 2):

try below code and access newest current employee Id like `Employee.Id`:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Employee Employee) {
 _db.Employees.Add(Employee);
 _db.SaveChanges();

 var id = Employee.Id;
 return RedirectToAction("EditEmployeeViewModel", new { id = id});
}
```