# Check if a record exists in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to know if a record exists in a database to avoid duplicate data.

Here is my code:

```
var cliente = rClientes.Retrive(c => c.Cliente == cli);

if (cliente == null)
{
    var newCliente = new Entities.Clientes { Cliente = cli, PuntoReorden = 0 };
    cliente = rClientes.Create(newCliente);
    cliente = rClientes.Retrive(c => c.Cliente == cli);
}
```

This is inside a foreach loop

Function `Create`:

```
public TEntity Create(TEntity toCreate)
{
    TEntity result = null;

    try
    {
       EntitySet.Add(toCreate);
       result = toCreate;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }

    return result;
}
```

Function `Retrieve`:

```
public TEntity Retrieve(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
            TEntity result = null;

            try
            {
                result = EntitySet.FirstOrDefault(criteria);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }

            return result;
}
```

The table has an identity column, so if I add the entity, I suppose I will have the id that is assigned right?

My question is, do I have to save changes every time I add a new record?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's always possible for a new item to be added immediately after you do such a check, so it doesn't actually mean it's safe for you to add a new item without causing duplicates.  Because of this such operations really need to be managed by the database, not the client.

Comment: So, to be sure of the id i have to save changes and then retrive the record?

Answer (score -1):

EF6 will automatically fill the id property of your object when you insert a record.

see this [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)