# Returning the Id of a newly created object in Entity Framework when using _context.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to find a good way to return either the Id or the entire newly created object when adding a new item to the context and saving in my repository. Is there a way to still do this with the way I have the functions split: one to add to the context, then a `SaveAll`?

Repository functions:

```
public Product AddProduct(Product product, string username)
{
    feedPostLike.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    feedPostLike.CreatedBy = username;

    _context.Add(product);
}

public bool SaveAll()
{
    return _context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

The way I am using the repository in the controller:

```
var newProd = _repository.AddProduct(productToSave, "superadmin");
_repository.SaveAll();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

Comment: productToSave should have the ID property populated, after calling the _repository.SaveAll(); method.

Comment: What does `AddProduct` return?