# Assigning products to categories with CategoryName given as foreign key in Product objects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a CMS system where a user can create a `Category` object, then the user can click on a created category and add `Product` objects to it. When a user is browsing products, they can click on a Category, which sends the CategoryId with the Post request to the products index page. The products index page then gets the category object matching the category Id passed, selects the Products list property belonging to that category and displays the products. `Category class` has a property of a `List<Product>` of Products.

I now have a `CSV data import form` which allows users to do the same thing but with a single CSV file upload.

The CSV file data (shaded grey) is a list of products. Note - category name column for each product (5th shaded column, i.e. "home", "heath&beauty"):

[image: CSV_Data.png]

This is the class for Product and Category:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool ShowOnIndex { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship that I have between Categories and Products is `One-to-Many` in SQL Server; a Category has many Products, a Product has only one Category.

In the following code I am trying to save the list of products into their correct categories by CategoryId. However, I didn't have the CategoryIds for each product in the CSV data so I'm manually collecting all the ids for the Categories in the loop.

```
public static async Task SaveProducts()
{
    var CategoryIds = new List<int>();

    foreach (var item in CategoriesList)
    {
        db.Categories.Add(item);
        var id = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Name == item.Name).Select(x => x.Id).ToString();
        CategoryIds.Add(int.Parse(id));
    }

    foreach (var item in ProductsList)
    {
        foreach (var id in CategoryIds)
        {
            var category = await db.Categories.FindAsync(id);
            category.Products.Add(item);
        }

    }

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

How do I somehow match the `CategoryName` value in the `Product` objects to the correct `Category Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that I could add each product the right category they belonged to all in one loop and I did it like this:

```
public static async Task SaveProducts()
        {

            foreach (var category in CategoriesList)
            {
                foreach (var product in ProductsList)
                {

                    if (product.CategoryName == category.Name)
                    {
                        category.Products.Add(product);
                    }
                }

                db.Categories.Add(category);
            }

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

As you can see, the only entity I added to the database was the Category object `category` each time. I did not have to add Products individually because I think Entity Framework knows the one-to-Many relationship between Categories and Products, so when I add a Category, Entity Framework will look at any foreign keys (here the List in the Categories class) and it will add a new Product object into the Products entity table in the database for every product object that is inside the Category's list of Products each time the for loop iterates the categories list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a transaction scope and save category with SaveChangesAsync() after that you can get the new ID and use in product relation. See this post
[How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)