# How do I retrieve a key field that is a primary key and automatically created in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What I am trying to do is create a record in 2 tables, `Communities` and `CommunityTeams`. Each of these have a primary key `ID` which is set as a `Identity 1.1` in SQL Server. Now, I would like to capture the key of `Communities` as a foreign key in `CommunityTeams`, but I have no way of knowing what that `ID` is.

Here is my code in ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Community Info
    model.CommunityType = Convert.ToInt32(fc["communityType"]);
    model.ComunityName = fc["communityName"];
    model.CommunityCity = fc["communityCity"];
    model.CommunityState = fc["communityState"];
    model.CommunityCounty = fc["communityCounty"];
    model.Population = Convert.ToInt32(fc["communityPop"]);

    // Save to Database
    model.Active = true;
    model.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    model.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
    model.Application_Complete = true;
    model.Application_Date = DateTime.Now;
    model.Payment_Complete = true;
    model.Payment_Date = DateTime.Now;
    model.Renewal = true;
    model.Renewal_Date = DateTime.Now;

    team.TeamLeader = true;
    team.Admin = true;
    var user = User.Identity.Name;
    team.UserName = user.ToString();
    team.CommunityId = 1;

    db.CommunityTeams.Add(team);
    db.Communities.Add(model);    

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Habitats");
}
```

Comment: Can you show the entity models (`Community` and `CommunityTeam`)? At least one of them should have navigation property, so at least tell if `Community` has `ICollection<CommunityTeam` or if `CommunityTeam` has `Community` property.

Comment: You mean a foreign key constraint

Comment: No, the **property**. Something like `public ICollection<CommunityTeam> Teams { get;set; }` in `Community` class or `public Community Community { get; set; }` in `CommunityTeam` class.

Comment: Possible answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework Ladislav Mrnka's answer?

Comment: I do not have anything like either of those ... just to be clear, i am trying to create a community record and a community team record at the same time, but I am trying to populate the Community ID record in Community Team, which is not known until the community ID record is created.

Comment: Hmm, without any of those, it's not possible to define `one-to-many` FK relationship (at least in EF 6 Code First).

Comment: i found my Answer ... thank you so much for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

I will admit that you have a navigation property to `Community` in your `CommunityTeam` entity.

Replace `team.CommunityId = 1;` by `team.Community = model;`. Then simply add the team entity, EF will create both `model` and `team`.

```
db.CommunityTeams.Add(team);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You can also split the save in two parts by calling `db.SaveChanges();` between the two `Add` call.
The first save will create the `Community` entity, EF will fill your primary key automatically so you can use it in `Team` entity for the second save.

Comment: So once I do the initial save and create the Community record ... how do I retrieve the CommunityId field to populate the CommunityTeam

Comment: EF will fill the primary key automatically with the newly created ID.