# EFPlus BulkInsert - How to get DB-generated IDs

Tags: entity-framework-extensions

Using MSSQL with IDENTITY column for IDs,
how can I get entity IDs synchronized with table IDs after calling BulkInsert?

```
context.BulkInsert(entities);
```

Neither of both achieves the requested result:

```
context.BulkSynchronize(entities);
context.BulkMerge(entities);
```

Assume we have one entity

```
var newSomething = new Something { Id = 0 };
```

and the corresponding TSQL table column definition

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Entity Framework automatically sets Id after calling SaveChanges()

```
context.SomethingSet.Add(newSomething);
context.SaveChanges();
Assert.IsTrue(newSomething.Id != 0)
```

See also [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

How does EFPlus provide a way of getting the Id of inserted entities?

Comment: Hello, I'm the author of the library. I'm not sure to understand your question. Could you provide us more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

The `Entity Framework Extensions` library should by default already return the ids for inserted entities.

For example, the following code should already work and return ids when using with BulkInsert.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.Lab
{
    public partial class Form_Request_Ids : Form
    {
        public Form_Request_DateNull()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // CLEAR
            using (var ctx = new CurrentContext())
            {
                ctx.EntitySimples.RemoveRange(ctx.EntitySimples);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            // TEST
            using (var ctx = new CurrentContext())
            {
                var list = new List<EntitySimple>();
                list.Add(new EntitySimple() { Id = 0, IntColumn = 1, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now });

                ctx.BulkInsert(list);
            }
        }

        public class CurrentContext : DbContext
        {
            public CurrentContext()
                : base("CodeFirstEntities")
            {
            }

            public DbSet<EntitySimple> EntitySimples { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Types().Configure(x => x.ToTable(GetType().DeclaringType != null ? GetType().DeclaringType.FullName.Replace(".", "_") + "_" + x.ClrType.Name : ""));

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }

        public class EntitySimple
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public int IntColumn { get; set; }

            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

If you still have the issue, try to contact us directly with an example info@zzzprojects.com or post your example here.

Comment: Correct answer.
For some reason my unit test did not get the same response. But now it works.