# How to get all saved Entity values in DbContext either via Events or override SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Need a centralized solution to get the resulting `Entity` as persisted to the Db, potentially inside the `SaveChangesAsync()` and `SaveChanges()` methods of my `DbContext` or via an event listener.

Need resulting entity value to contain all new `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd[Updated/etc]()` properties.  i.e.`RowVersion`, `Updated`, etc..

The purpose is to communicate the before and after of the `Entity` for concurrency communication.

This is what I have thus far:  This first method incurrs an extra, unnecessary Db hit.

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken() )
{
    var before = ChangeTracker.Entries().AsEnumerable().First();

    var res = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    /* ********************************************************           
       I can do the following, but this results in an extra 
       DbQuery. I know that if this were a  consumer 
       method with entity, after I called SaveChangesAsync() it 
       would have the new resulting values.  Just not sure how 
       to access here inside SaveChangesAsync()?
       ********************************************************** */
    await ChangeTracker.Entries().AsEnumerable().First().ReloadAsync(); 
    /* ********************************************************
       ^ Additionally, ReloadAsync has a "Note, however, that an 
       Added entity may not yet have had its permanent key value 
       created. 
       ********************************************************** */
    var after = ChangeTracker.Entries().AsEnumerable().First();

    return res;
}
```

Additionally I have subscribed to the new *state change events* `Tracked` and `StateChagned` that are mentioned or linked on github issue [EntityFrameworkCore - Lifecycle hooks #626](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/626#issuecomment-379954244):
For Ex:

```
public class StateListener : IEntityStateListener
{
    public void StateChanging(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState newState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "  Changing {0} from {1} to {2}.",
            entry.Entity.GetType().Name, entry.EntityState, newState);
    }

    public void StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, 
        EntityState oldState, bool fromQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "  Changed {0} to {1} from {2}.",
            entry.Entity.GetType().Name, entry.EntityState, oldState);
    }

    public void StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState,
        bool skipInitialFixup, bool fromQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "  Changed {0} from {1} to {2}.",
            entry.Entity.GetType().Name, oldState, entry.EntityState);
    }
}
```

However the `newState` and the `InternalEntityEntry` in `StateChanged` all posess the values that should save and not the new values that are set by the Db, such `RowVersion`, `Changed` etc..

Comment: Your update should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for those with similar search** - Upon asking this question I had a fundamental misunderstanding.  I believed an entity persisted to the Db would have all its values updated on `SaveChanges[Async]()`.  I believed this because that is the behavior of Primary Keys as described in "[How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework#answer-5212787)"

This is not the case for properties that are `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd[Updated/etc]()` and are not RowVersion or PrimaryKeys.

With this understanding, any possible solution presumably would require a query to the Db.  I considered adding such a query to the `OnCommandExecuting` and then working with result in `OnCommandExecuted` but abandoned due to its nature.