# How to get id of new created child?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Getting parent's ID is quite easy, as answered here: [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyEntities.AddObject(myNewObject);
  context.SaveChanges();

  int id = myNewObject.Id; // Yes it's here
}
```

However, I'm asking myself how I can get an ID of new created child entity (one-to-many), where a child has been add to the child collection, like:

```
existingParent.Children.Add(newChild);


public int Save(Parent parent)
{
   context.Update(parent);
   context.SaveChanges();    
   return ???;
}
```

Comment: a parent has many children ,  which child do you want to return ?

Comment: What about `newChild.Id`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: @itminus: the id of the new created child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unreasonable to return the id of the new created child in `Save` method.

For your current code, `Save` is not the only purpose to save `Children` property. Let's assume some scenario like below:

1. Update `Parenet` without changing `Children` property, what is your expected return value for `Save`
2. Update `Parenet` with adding multiple new `Child`, what is your expected return value
3. Update `Parenet` with removing `Child`, what will it return

You may consider get the new `Id` outside `public int Save(Parent parent)` after calling `context.SaveChanges();`.

Demo Code:

```
        var parent1 = _db.Parent.Include(p => p.Children).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
        var child3 = new Child { Name = "N3"};
        var child4 = new Child { Name = "N4" };
        parent1.Children.Add(child3);
        parent1.Children.Add(child4);

        _db.Update(parent1);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        var childId3 = child3.Id;
        var childId4 = child4.Id;
```

Comment: Many thanks Tao Zhou - it works! If I may... one more question: if I use repository pattern and pass just the parent to the Save procedure (children added in the controller). How would it work that way?