# Get list of Identity Ids inserted in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a list that I am adding to a table through EF core. Table also has an identity column. I need the values of list of identity values once saveChanges is called. This function can be called my multiple progams at the same time.

```
using(var ctx = new DataReviewContext2())
{
   foreach(var value in values)
   {
       value.Username = user;
       value.Changed = DateTime.Now;
       ctx.ChangeLog.Add(value);
   }
   ctx.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve all Ids after calling SaveChaning in that context. The id will be automatically filled for you:

```html
using(var ctx = new DataReviewContext2())
{
   foreach(var value in values)
   {
       value.Username = user;
       value.Changed = DateTime.Now;
       ctx.ChangeLog.Add(value);
   }
   ctx.SaveChanges();
   
   // Add this to get all userIs 
   var Ids = values.Select(c=>c.UserId).ToList();

}
```

Comment: If I try to get Values again, will it contain the new Ids?