# How to insert triangle relationship into DB using EF

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, sql-insert

Hello i have a database with 3 tables designed in a triangle like below:

```
File  has many Page 
Page  has many Segment
File  has many Segment
```

When i try to insert the an entity of type `File` i get the following error:

> - InnerException  {"The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Segment_File_FileId\". The conflict occurred in
>     database \"mydatabase\", table \"dbo.File\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe
>     statement has been terminated."}  System.Exception
>     {Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

**Models**

```
public class File
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Segment> Segments{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Pages> Pages{get;set;}
}
public class Page
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Segment> Segments{get;set;}
}
public class Segment
{
  public int Id{get;set;}

  public Page Page{get;set;}
  public int PageId{get;set;}  //foreign key from page

  public File File{get;set;}
  public int FileId{get;set;} //foreign key from file
}
```

**Context**

```
public class MyContext: DbContext {
        public DbSet<Segment> Segments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
        public SXSContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options):base(options) {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

            modelBuilder.Entity<File>(ent => {
                ent.ToTable("File");
                ent.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                ent.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Page>(ent => {
                ent.ToTable("Page");
                ent.HasKey(x => x.Id);

                ent.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
                ent.Property(x => x.FileId).IsRequired();
                ent.HasOne(y => y.File).WithMany(t => t.Pages).HasForeignKey(g => g.FileId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Segment>(ent => {
                ent.ToTable("Segment");
                ent.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                ent.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
                ent.Property(x => x.PageId).IsRequired();
                ent.Property(x => x.FileId).IsRequired();
                ent.HasOne(y => y.Page).WithMany(t => t.Segments).HasForeignKey(g => g.PageId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                ent.HasOne(y => y.File).WithMany(t => t.Segments).HasForeignKey(g => g.FileId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            await Task.Delay(1);

            DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            SXSContext context = new SXSContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            List<Page> pages = new List<Page>{
                new Page{
                Segments = new List<Segment> {
                    new Segment{  },
                    new Segment{  },
                    new Segment{ }}
                },
                new Page{
                Segments = new List<Segment> {
                    new Segment{  },
                    new Segment{  }}
                }
            };
            File file = new File {  Pages = pages };
            context.Files.Add(file);

            context.SaveChanges();
            int val = await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
```

P.S Could it be a problem that i have `Segment`'s foreign keys as `required` and they might get inserted before their parents `File` and `Page`?

How should a schema like this be inserted ?I start with a `File` and i have `Pages` and `Segments` they do not posess `id`'s until insertion.

Can they be inserted in one operation or they must be inserted starting from the root which in my case is `File` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar question and this is workaround that I followed:

First you should insert non dependent entities and trigger `SaveChanges / SaveChangesAsync` so that your entities will get id-s (for more information check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5212787/3887114) from another thread), in your case, first you have to add  `File` and call `SaveChanges / SaveChangesAsync`, then the same you should do for `Page`, after each step, you'll get id-s filled in.
After that you can use third insert (which in your case is `Segment`) without getting any errors, as you can have all referenced id-s in place.

Comment: `Page` depends on `File` in my case.So in my case i could insert the `File` and then get its id and from there just insert `Page`-s with their `Segments` and all would get linked ? `Segment` needs foreign key of both `FIle` and `Page` while `Page` needs only `File`

Comment: Missed that link in my previous version of my answer. Indeed, this approach means that you are inserting entities one by one, or group after group, but keep the order, and do not forget calling `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` on them, as that step fills in the id for your entity. Updated my answer accordingly.