# C# Entity Framework: Insert Child Entity and Update Parent, One Transaction

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I add a new child record in Entity Framework and update the `ParentId` reference key?

We have an `Employee` and a `ProductSales` table.

The `Employee` table contains column of most recent `ProductSaleId`.

If I add a new entry to `ProductSale`, it will acquire a new identity column in the SQL Server database.

```
lastProductSale = new ProductSale { Product = "Furniture", Amount= 1000, EmployeeId = 5};
_dbContext.Add(productSale);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
int lastProductSaleId = lastProductSale.productSaleId;
```

Now updating the `Employee` table reference key like this:

```
employee.ProductSaleId = lastProductSaleId;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

We know the `EmployeeId` which is 5. However, this takes two transactions from two save operations.

I want to this to be done in one transaction. How can this be completed?

Using EF Core 3.1,
Entities are scaffolded with foreign keys

**Resource:**

[How can I retrieve Id of inserted entity using Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-retrieve-id-of-inserted-entity-using-entity-framework)

Comment: hi @devlincarnate yeah, I have a foreign key setup in DB and EF

Comment: Oh wait... LastProductSaleId is only the id of the most recent product sold.  Sorry, I misunderstood the relationship.  As far as I know, you will have to do 2 saves.  However, you can use `TransactionScope`  to manage the case where one save fails.

Comment: Note that this is a problematic database design. You should avoid storing `LastProductSaleId` unless you absolutely know, because you tried it, that computing it on demand is too slow.

Comment: Yes, this database design has problem. You don't need LastProductSaleId in employee table. Whenever you want display employee's latest sale, then get latest sale data using employeeid + date. Anyway, if you want one transaction, it's impossible because you need to use savechanges to be able to get new id.

Comment: hi @Asherguru I agree, I told db architect that, just doing my job, but question is more conceptual, Insert child and  update Parent in one Transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework automatic scaffold was setup.
So the following worked,
Instead of using `employee.ProductSaleId`, just use `ProductSale`, and update the Parent directly.

```
productSale = new ProductSale { Product = "Furniture", Amount= 1000, EmployeeId = 5};
employee.ProductSale = productSale;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Entity Framework Core will automatically adjust with Insert or Update